# Update SQL statement with subquery

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a stored procedure called `Delete_CreditPayment` as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_CreditPayment] (@CollectionID nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Acc_CreditDocuments
    Set Acc_Status = 3010001
    WHERE Acc_DocumentRef = (SELECT Acc_DocumentRef 
    From Acc_CreditDocuments 
    WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID);
END
```

It works when SELECT statement has only one invoice, `Acc_DocumentRef` but if it has more than one values, Microsoft SQL Server shows the following error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

So, how can I edit my stored procedure above to accept more than one values? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_CreditPayment] (@CollectionID nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Acc_CreditDocuments
    Set Acc_Status = 3010001
    WHERE Acc_DocumentRef IN (SELECT Acc_DocumentRef 
    From Acc_CreditDocuments 
    WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID);
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` is not ideal. You don't need to add sub-query in `WHERE` condition in this case (since you are using the same table in the sub-query). You could do it directly like this:

```
UPDATE Acc_CreditDocuments
Set Acc_Status = 3010001
WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID);
```

So your whole query (alter procedure) should be like this one:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Delete_CreditPayment] (@CollectionID nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Acc_CreditDocuments
    Set Acc_Status = 3010001
    WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID);
END
```

When you get any error like `Subquery returned more than 1 value...` you are probably doing something like this: `WHERE a = (1,2,3)` so instead of `=` operator use `IN` like `WHERE a IN (1,2,3)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I must use Acc_DocumentRef as an invoice. This is the reason why I am using subquery in WHERE statement. Now my problem is solved by using bansi answer.

Comment: @Jowie - Can I know why you must use `Acc_DocumentRef`?

Comment: `Acc_DocumentRef` is Invoice no in my application. So, the whole process is like if credit payment is deleted from the table, invoice status will be set to `Open` which parameter code is `3010001`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE a
SET Acc_Status = 3010001
FROM dbo.Acc_CreditDocuments a
WHERE EXISTS(
     SELECT 1 
     FROM dbo.Acc_CreditDocuments b
     WHERE b.Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID
          AND a.Acc_DocumentRef = b.Acc_DocumentRef
)
```

Or this -

```
UPDATE dbo.Acc_CreditDocuments
SET Acc_Status = 3010001
WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT Acc_DocumentRef 
    From Acc_CreditDocuments 
    WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID)
```

This query is retruning more than value. You need to modified your query so that it will return only one row. you can do it either by putting `distinct` , `top 1` or modifying your above query as below according to your requirement.

```
 WHERE Acc_DocumentRef IN (SELECT Acc_DocumentRef 
    From Acc_CreditDocuments 
    WHERE Acc_DocumentNo = @CollectionID);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your details explanation and you made me very clear about this question. I used `IN` instead of `=`.